# Telegraf, new_chat_members не работает

Tags: node.js, telegraf

Используем telegraf и nodejs для создания телграмм-бота. Так как (насколько я знаю после поисков) от апи телеграмма мы не можем получить список всех чатов бота и список всех участников определённого чата, мы завели свою базу. Задача бота - записывать в базу новых участников группового чата и при попытке ими написать сообщение удалять его и присылать своё с просьбой обратиться к администратору для получения возможности писать в групповой чат. После этого блокировать этому пользователю возможность писать ([restrictChatMember](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#restrictchatmember)). На тех пользователей, что были в чате до бота - не обращать внимание. Также к боту есть админка, позволяющая просматривать базу чатов и их участников и давать/забирать право писать. Короче, проблема в том, что в групповом чате заказчика не срабатывает ни new_chat_members, ни left_chat_member. Есть какой-то ещё способ контролировать входящих и выходящих пользователей?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Может этот чат подключён к каналу? Тогда комментарии из канала попадают в чат, но фактически пользователи к чату не присоединяются.

Comment: Ну насколько я вижу это всё-таки группа, в которую можно вступить и писать сообщения. Текстовые сообщения бот ловит. Сообщения о вступлении и выходе пользователя из группы в чат не попадают, и бот их тоже не получает.

Comment: вы решили этот вопрос, просто у меня точно такая же проблема :(?